# Regarding loop structure in Matlab for an iterative procedure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to code a loop in Matlab that iteratively solves for an optimal vector s of zeros and ones. This is my code

```
N = 150;
s = ones(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    if s(i) == 0
        i = i + 1;
    else
        i = i;
    end
    select = s;
    HI = (item_c' * (weights.*s)) * (1/(weights'*s));
    s(i) = 0;
    CI = (item_c' * (weights.*s)) * (1/(weights'*s));
    standarderror_afterex = sqrt(var(CI - CM));
    standarderror_priorex = sqrt(var(HI - CM));
    ratio = (standarderror_afterex - standarderror_priorex)/(abs(mean(weights.*s) - weights'*select));
    ratios(i) = ratio;
    s(i) = 1;
end

[M,I] = min(ratios);
s(I) = 0;
```

This code sets the element to zero in s, which has the lowest ratio. But I need this procedure to start all over again, using the new s with one zero, to find the ratios and exclude the element in s that has the lowest ratio. I need that over and over until no ratios are negative.
Do I need another loop, or do I miss something?

I hope that my question is clear enough, just tell me if you need me to explain more.

Thank you in advance, for helping out a newbie programmer.

**Edit**

I think that I need to add some form of while loop as well. But I can't see how to structure this. This is the flow that I want

With all items included (`s(i) = 1` for all i), calculate HI, CI and the standard errors and list the ratios, exclude item i (`s(I) = 0`) which corresponds to the lowest negative ratio.
With the new s, including all ones but one zero, calculate HI, CI and the standard errors and list the ratios, exclude item i, which corresponds to the lowest negative ratio.
With the new s, now including all ones but two zeros, repeat the process.
Do this until there is no negative element in ratios to exclude.

Hope that it got more clear now.

Comment: I don't 100% follow what's going on, but I strongly suspect your problem has to do with trying to modify the loop index. I'm actually not sure what happens in MATLAB (or any other language for that matter that has this style of for-loop syntax) when you modify `i` inside the loop, but I think that during the next iteration it most likely just gets set to whatever it was going to be next anyway. So in your case, I suspect the loop body doesn't repeat in the case of `~(s(i) == 0)` as you seem to have intended. I recommend switching to something like `i=1; while i<=N; ...; end`

Comment: I have that modification of the loop index since I don't want `s(i)`to be set to one if it has been set to zero earlier. But I guess it's kind of bad practice, right?

Comment: Would it work if you just put the inside of the loop inside the `if s(i)~=0` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I want to go through a few things before I list my code.  These are just how *I* would try to do it.  Not necessarily the best way, or fastest way even (though I'd think it'd be pretty quick).  I tried to keep the structure as you had in your code, so you could follow it nicely (even though I'd probably meld all the calculations down into a single function or line).

Some features that I'm using in my code:

1. `bsxfun`: Learn this! It is amazing how it works and can speed up code, and makes some things easier.

   ```
   v = rand(n,1);
   A = rand(n,4);
   % The two lines below compute the same value:
   W = bsxfun(@(x,y)x.*y,v,A);
   W_= repmat(v,1,4).*A;
   ```

   `bsxfun` dot multiplies the `v` vector with each column of `A`.
   Both `W` and `W_` are matrices the same size as `A`, but the first will be much faster (usually).
2. Precalculating dropouts:  I made `select` a matrix, where before it was a vector.  This allows me to then form a variable `included` using logical constructs.  The `~(eye(N))` produces an identity matrix and negates it.  By logically "and"ing it with select, then the $i$th column is now select, with the $i$th element dropped out.
3. You were explicitly calculating `weights'*s` as the denominator in each for-loop.  By using the above matrix to calculate this, we can now do a `sum(W)`, where the `W` is essentially `weights.*s` in each column.
4. Take advantage of column-wise operations: the `var()` and the `sqrt()` functions are both coded to work along the columns of a matrix, outputting the action for a matrix in the form of a row vector.

Ok.  the full thing.  Any questions let me know:

```
% Start with everything selected:
select = true(N);

stop = false; % Stopping flag:
while (~stop)
  % Each column leaves a variable out...
  included = ~eye(N) & select;  

  % This calculates the weights with leave-one-out:
  W = bsxfun(@(x,y)x.*y,weights,included);
  % You can comment out the line below, if you'd like...
  W_= repmat(weights,1,N).*included;  % This is the same as previous line.

  % This calculates the weights before dropping the variables:
  V = bsxfun(@(x,y)x.*y,weights,select);

  % There's different syntax, depending on whether item_c is a 
  %  vector or a matrix...
  if(isvector(item_c))
    HI = (item_c' * V)./(sum(V));
    CI = (item_c' * W)./(sum(W));
  else
    % For example: item_c is a matrix... 
    % We have to use bsxfun() again
    HI = bsxfun(@rdivide, (item_c' * V),sum(V));
    CI = bsxfun(@rdivide, (item_c' * W),sum(W));
  end

  standarderror_afterex = sqrt(var(bsxfun(@minus,HI,CM)));
  standarderror_priorex = sqrt(var(bsxfun(@minus,CI,CM)));
  % or:
  % 
  % standarderror_afterex = sqrt(var(HI - repmat(CM,1,size(HI,2))));
  % standarderror_priorex = sqrt(var(CI - repmat(CM,1,size(CI,2))));


  ratios = (standarderror_afterex - standarderror_priorex)./(abs(mean(W) - sum(V)));

  % Identify the negative ratios:
  negratios = ratios < 0;
  if ~any(negratios) 
    % Drop out of the while-loop:
    stop = true;
  else
    % Find the most negative ratio:
    neginds = find(negratios);
    [mn, mnind] = min(ratios(negratios));

    % Drop out the most negative one...
    select(neginds(mnind),:) = false;  
  end

end % end while(~stop)

% Your output:
s = select(:,1);
```

If for some reason it doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the lesson! I do get an error however:

Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in test (line 30)
    HI = bsxfun(@rdivide, (item_c' * V),sum(V)');

item_c is a matrix. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in calculating the `V` variable.  Also, I think the `sum(V)'` should just be `sum(V)`.   I think that should do it... Sorry, again.

Comment: Thanks @aepound ! Now I get this error

Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in test (line 34)
  standarderror_afterex = sqrt(var(HI - CM));

Comment: What are is the size of CM? Likely we'll have to use a bsxfun() to perform the subtraction there, too...

Comment: I think that should fix it.... This is essentially the process that I go through when re-engineering an algorithm to be faster/more vectorized... Sorry. The little things will catch ya! :)

Comment: If item_c is nxp, then CM is px1.

Comment: Right.  Did the last change fix it for you?

Comment: I think so, I'll get back to you if there's any problem. Many thanks! :)